# T-SQL Replacing Nulls with Empty String

Tags: t-sql

I have the following union query:

```
select
  'type1' as type,
  id,
  add_date
from Table A
where type = type1
union all
select
  'type2' as type,
  id,
  '' as add_date
from Table B
```

Since add_date isn't applicable to type 2, it is providing 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 for any records returned. I could change the statement from '' as add_date to NULL as add_date, but the user is asking if I can remove the null from the report and leave the result as an empty string where applicable. What is the best way to  accomplish this? Thanks.!

Comment: Cast add_date to a character type in the 1st select (may break your report)

Comment: Replace it in your application code with empty string, and select NULL in the B query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use null and cast the result as a string with the `ISNULL` function applied:

```
SELECT [type], id, ISNULL(CAST(add_date as VARCHAR), '') AS add_date
FROM (
SELECT 'type1' as [type]
      ,id
      ,add_date
  FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT 'type2' as [type]
      ,id
      ,null as add_date
  FROM TableB
) inside_query
```

This will allow you to provide blanks instead of 1/1/1900 or `NULL` keyword.  You can also change the `CAST` to a `CONVERT` if you need to provide specific date formatting.

Comment: For a more portable solution for other RDBMSs, use `COALESCE()` instead of `ISNULL()`.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, but I am still getting the 1/1/1900.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select
   'type1' as type,
   id,
   CAST(add_date AS VARCHAR) as add_date
from Table A
where type = type1
union all
select
  'type2' as type,
  id,
  '' as add_date
from Table B
```